# Magento 2 - mage.php equivalent

Tags: magento2

I am trying to figure out what the equivalent of the following piece of Magento 1 code would be in Magento 2.

I am trying to include magento 2 into a external file as follows:

Magento 1 Code:

```
$MAGENTO_BASE_DIR = '/mySite.com/'
require($MAGENTO_BASE_DIR.'app/Mage.php');
```

Would the following Magento 2 Code suffice:

```
$MAGENTO_BASE_DIR = '/mySite.com/';
require($MAGENTO_BASE_DIR . 'app/bootstrap.php');
```

Not sure if the above magento 2 code is entirely correct?

Thanks in advance